# How to install koalas for spark 2.4?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-koalas

I want to run my pandas code on pyspark but for that I need koalas.
How can I install and use koalas with spark 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to pip install it with command prompt, try: `pip install koalas`

Koalas and PySpark are different things. Koalas is an in between of Spark and Pandas as it has the Pandas syntax with some of the Spark distributed abilities but not all of them.